# Evaluar POST o Sesión PHP

Tags: php, post, seguridad

¿Qué evaluo primero? El POST o la presencia de una variable de sesion?
Estas condicionales serán para validar si el usuario esta "logeado" si lo esta tiene permiso para estar en esta zona de usuarios y tambien para validar que se esta accediendo al archivo mediante algún método de PHP (POST)
Pero no sé que debería validar primero, yo creo que la sesión pero me gustaría pesar opiniones
Algo como:

```
if($_POST){
  if(isset($_SESSION["name"]){
      instructions
  }
}
```

O

```
if(isset($_SESSION["name"]){
  if($_POST){
      instructions
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo validar primero las variables de session

**Ejemplo**

```
<?php
   IF(!ISSET($_SESSION['name']){
      header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
   }
   $user = $_POST['user'];
   Instrucciones
   ...
```

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación

Answer (score 1):

A mi parecer deberías primero validar que haya iniciado sesión. Primero te conectas y después puedes realizar acciones dentro de la página, no es que primero vayas a mandar datos por un formulario y después te conectas.

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión Sebastián, asi lo haré